# Printing variables on a Tkinter GUI ( Selenium, Tkinter, Json )

Tags: python, json, selenium, tkinter

my aim is to be able to print out variables defined from data which has been webscraped using selenium. I have grabbed the data needed and i **think** i have successfully assigned them to their own variable, im now trying to print this onto my tkinter GUI, however when i try and do this it tells me that the variable is not assigned, im pretty stumped on where to go from here so any help will be appreciated.

Also, sorry for the amount of comments in the code, i need to present this later and it helps me understand whats going on.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import json
from json import loads

def Sel():
    Search_Button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ValidatedSearch.form-control.form-control-lg")
    Search_Button.send_keys(address.get())
    Search_Button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    Data = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='Content']/div/div[2]/div/div/pre/code").text
   #print(Data)  
   
    def jprint(obj):
                                                                                    # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
     text = json.loads(Data)

     #print(text)
     print()
     print(text['block_account'],text['balance'],text['amount'])
     
     block_account = text['block_account']
     balance = text['balance']
     amount = text['amount']
     
    jprint(Data) 
       
def close_app():
    root.destroy()  
       
# ---- Account Balance ----
Label(root,text="Account Balance:" + balance).place(x=120,y=110)
```

The error im getting is:

```
Label(root,text="Account Balance:" + balance).place(x=120,y=110)

NameError: name 'balance' is not defined
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error. There also seems to be a fair amount of code that is not necessary to reproduce this problem. It would help if you removed it so that your code example is a [mcve].

Comment: My bad, updated it to what the main things needed are.

Comment: That error seems pretty self-explanatory. `balance` is a variable local to `jprint`, so nothing outside of that function can see it.

Comment: I understand that it is defined under the jprint function, but is there any way to turn that into a global variable? Or is there any way to be able to call that variable into the GUI part of this?